# How can I visually see the range of RSU?

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, sumo

Is there a way, I can outline the range of RSU in omnet++?. I know how to set the range of RSU, as shown in the code below. But how do I actually see that range. Because, I want to see if the how does the transmission happens outside the RSU.

I tried adding parameters in RSU class and .ned class but that does not work at all. Sort of lost here what to do.

Here is how I set up range for RSU

```cpp
Thesis.rsu[0].appl.dataROI = 500m
Thesis.rsu[0].appl.minDistance = 0m
Thesis.rsu[0].appl.maxDistance = 500m
```

I just want to see if it's possible that in the simulation it shows RSU range.

Comment: You can show the maximum interference distance by setting `*.connectionManager.drawMaxIntfDist = true`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, that worked :). Also, is there a way I can change that? either decease it or increase it? It didn't work with parameters that I listed above...

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the maximum interference distance by setting the following property in your omnetpp.ini

```
*.connectionManager.drawMaxIntfDist = true
```

However, this shows only the maximum distance where the signal is considered by other nodes in the network. Setting the value for `maxInterfDist` to a very high value doesn't imply that the signal is successful received at another node within that distance.